# LCD display problem

Tags: microcontroller

I can not get an explanation why my LCD does not work with PIC18F4520 when it was working perfectly using PIC18F458 on the same speed and the same software (but of course recompiled for PIC18F4520). If somebody knows what is the difference between the two MCs configuration, Please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There was difference between the ADCON1 register values for the two MCs. For 458 it is 0X07 and for 4520 it was 0Fh. The time delays had some 0.75 ratio between the two MCs. We figured it out by trial and error method and at-last it worked we could see what we wanted to display on the LCD. We used the same circuits for the two as there was no difference between their pin configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally speaking there shouldnt be any problem, condition to the following:

-Port B (if connected to the LCD) is configured as digitial I/O.
-Same Oscillator is being used.

Are you using the same circuit for the two cases.?

Try out the sequence of commands mentioned in the following link
http://joshuagalloway.com/lcd.html